# Should I use a NodeJS global to make config properties available to my application?

Tags: node.js, express

My question is relatively simple:

In NodeJS you have the ability to set globals using

`GLOBAL.myConfigObject = {...}`

My question for the developer community is whether or not this is best practice. If not, what would be a better way to relay config variables (such as api-url or Port or ip address) to the entire application.

Comment: I wouldn't because then as a developer that came in after you to maintain the application, i would have to figure out where that global is set and what all can affect it if something weird is happening. but that's just my opinion to this very opinion-based question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of setting a global for the config, use a global for the environment you're launching in. Setup a config directory that has each of your environments:

**config/local.js**

```
module.exports = {
    port: 3000,
    ipAddress: "127.0.0.1"
}
```

**config/production.js**

```
module.exports = {
    port: 443,
    ipAddress: "8.8.8.8"
}
```

in your main file where you spin up your server:

**server.js**

```
var config = require("./config/" + process.env.NODE_ENV)
// use your config however you need it
```

spinning up your server from the command line, you can then do:

`NODE_ENV=local node server.js`

This way, you have a single global variable indicating your environment, but you can use whatever configuration variables you need for that environment.

Comment: This was very enlightening. I've been trying to figure out the best way to manage multiple environments without having different config files for the different environments, but the way you describe setting an environment variable to switch config files makes much more sense for my project.

Answer (score 0):

most common way for these config such as port , and api_keys , is enviorment variable.

bash

`$ set PORT=8080`

you can access environment variable like that

node.js

`node> process.env.PORT`

Answer (score -1):

In my project case, it's very useful to set a connection config. I use it for all of my server and if I have to change my database, I can switch pretty easily