# How do i setup my code for production vs local in node.js?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

So technically I have finished coded my web app, and I want to deploy it to production.

How do I separate between codes in production in local?

For example in local there are many codes that are depending on `'http://localhost:3000'` vs production `'http://www.example.com'`. Even in facebook I have keep changing the URL name back and forth, because Sometimes I want to test it on local Dev.

and same goes to mongodb as well, for local i will use local version, for production I have to switch it again. It is really redundant.

Comment: there are an infinite number of ways to answer this, but to start you can set a development command vs a production command in your package.json scripts

Comment: This might get you in the right direction http://stackoverflow.com/a/35067376/3696076

Answer (score 0):

use config files for example this one is good.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/config